# setting properties for another class from appDelegate

Tags: ios, properties, appdelegate

I'm trying to quite simply set properties of a class called 'Bank' from the appDelegate, but it is not working as I thought it would. Somehow the properties are being set fine in the appDelegate class, so as long as I call the properties from the appDel it works, but as soon as I call those same properties from any other class they return null. Here is all the relevant code.

App Del.m

```
#import "MusikerAppDelegate.h"
#import "MusikerViewController.h"

@implementation MusikerAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize tbc;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    AudioTableViewController *ATVC = [[AudioTableViewController alloc] init];
    MusikerViewController *MusicVC = [[MusikerViewController alloc] init];
    tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: MusicVC, ATVC, nil];

    [ATVC release];
    [MusicVC release];

    Bank *daBank = [[Bank alloc] init];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        daBank.managedObjectContext = context;
    daBank.myDate = [NSDate date];

    if (!daBank.myDate) {
        NSLog(@"no date at point A");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Date at appDel : %@",daBank.myDate);
    }

    if (!daBank.managedObjectContext) {
        NSLog(@"PROBLEM. NO MANAGED OBJECT CONTEXT!! -MUSIKER APP DELEGATE at point A");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"ManagedObjectContext created at point A");
        NSLog(@"Context: %@",daBank.managedObjectContext);
        NSLog(@"PS Coord : %@",daBank.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator);
        NSLog(@"MOM : %@", daBank.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel);
        NSLog(@"Entities : %@",[[daBank.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel entities] valueForKey:@"name"]);
    }


    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window addSubview:tbc.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

... (more methods)
No, when I call on NSLog to print the date, NSManagedObject, etc. It prints everything initialized and working perfectly.

Here is the class that contains the properties being set.
Bank.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import "AudioFile.h"
#import "AudioTableViewController.h"
#import "MusikerAppDelegate.h"

@interface Bank : NSObject {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
     NSDate *myDate;
     NSString *recPath;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext   *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate                   *myDate;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString                 *recPath;
//@property (copy) NSString *docPath;

- (id)init;

+ (NSString *)getDataPath:(NSString *)fileExtDate;

-(BOOL)addAudioFileEntityToModel;
-(BOOL)removeAudioFromModel:(id)audio;
-(NSMutableArray *)getFetchArray;

@end
```

and the implementation file
Bank.m

```
//
//  Bank.m
//  Musiker
//
//  Created by Lucas Gaylord on 7/7/13.
//  Copyright 2013 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Bank.h"
//#import "AudioFile.h"

@implementation Bank
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize myDate;
@synthesize recPath;
//@synthesize docPath = _docPath;


- (NSMutableArray *)getFetchArray {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    if(!managedObjectContext) {
        //handel error
    }

    NSLog(@"AT PLACE A");

    NSLog(@"Context: %@",managedObjectContext);
    NSLog(@"PS Coord : %@",managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator);
    NSLog(@"MOM : %@", managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel);
    NSLog(@"Entities : %@",[[managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel entities] valueForKey:@"name"]);

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AudioFile" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    [request release];

    return mutableFetchResults;
}
```

...(more methods)
Now, when I call on NSLog to print the same properties i set in the appDel, they all return null. This happens anywhere and everywhere I get those properties outside of the appDel.

I have no idea what the problem is. I've tried calling self.managedObjectContext. I've tried @class MusikAppDelegate before the implementation of Bank.m. I've printed out the properties to the console in every class of my application but they always return null except when they're called from the appDel. Please, please explain.

Comment: How do you get the instance of the bank in the cases which fail?

Comment: @Wain  - (Bank *)daBank 
{    
    if(!daBank) {
        daBank = [[Bank alloc] init];
    }
 
 return daBank;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing the managedObjectContext and other properties in Bank's initializer fixed it.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
    MusikerAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        self.managedObjectContext = context;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never appear to save your `daBank` instance, so it's probably being destroyed. So, when you try to get the bank details (which you don't show an example of) you're probably either getting `nil` when you request the instance, or you're creating a new instance (which will not have any of the settings you're expecting because it's new).

The app delegate generally isn't the place to hold information like this, but you need some object to be the owner of your bank instance so that when anyone needs it they go to that owner and ask for the instance.

---

Your additional code (though a little unclear due to the cast) generally shows that you're creating a new instance.

Consider passing your bank instance from the app delegate to your root view controller and then having the root view controller pass it on to any other view controller it creates which needs it.

---

[General intro guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH1-SW1). [Objective-C overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210). [Specifically sending and receiving messages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW2).

Comment: the app delegate is the best place for this kind of information because im using a CoreData structure that implements the NSManagedObjectContext in the appDelegate like most other CoreData structures. This tutorial from Apple [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/01_StartingOut.html) assigns the managedObjectContext property to its main class the same way I'm trying (but obviously failing) to do it here.

Comment: actually I got it. I think you were right and I was over complicating things. I just initialized Bank's managedObjectContext in Bank's initializer and now its working fine.

Comment: The app delegate is not the correct place and apple putting the managed object context in the app delegate is not necessarily the correct solution. This is the difference between 'working' and 'correct'.

Comment: ok. why would it b better to have my root view controller owning my bank instance instead of doing everything in Bank's init? wouldnt I have the same problem every time I made a new instance of my root view controller?

Comment: When do you recreate the root view controller? The point is that you describe wanting to reuse the same bank instance but your solution is to keep creating new ones...

Comment: im trying to ask how I would pass around a bank instance without creating a new one or declaring it in my appDel. Even if my root view controller owned my bank instance, in order for me to call the bank instance I would first have to create a new instance of my root view controller.

Comment: when you create a new view controller instance, call a method on it to set the bank instance.

Comment: but then how do I pass around the bank instance without having to create a new view controller instance every time i need the bank? Maybe theres a tutorial or piece of code u could give me a link to so I can understand a little better.

Comment: You need a tutorial on objects and methods. The bank is just like a string, it can be passed between instances.

Comment: Could u post a link to a good tutorial. I previously learned java and i think thats where I'm confusing myself with instance variables and objects.

Comment: when i click on that link it says page not found and then redirects me